# CSS image rollover map and jQuery : how to use a second li list?

Tags: jquery, css, rollover, imagemap

I'm currently using this clickable map ([Wolf's map](http://winstonwolf.pl/css,europe.html)) but I would like to use a second li list of countries in addition of the one that serves as a foundation for the script. The second menu cannot be in the same DIV as the map for presentation reasons. I've been searching through the JQuery documentation to understand how I can trigger an action on another element than the one selected but I'm not sure I've got it right - probably not as it is not working.

The original script looks like this :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

 var new_map='<span class="map"><span class="s1" /><span class="s2" /><span class="s3" /><span class="s4" /><span class="s5" /><span class="s6" /><span class="s7" /><span class="s8" /><span class="s9" /><span class="s10" /><span class="s11" /><span class="s12" /><span class="s13" /><span class="s14" /><span class="s15" /><span class="s16" /><span class="s17" /><span class="s18" /></span>';
 var new_bg=$("<span>");
 new_bg.addClass("bg");
 $("#europe li a").append(new_map);
 $("#europe li a").append(new_bg);

});
```

What I would like to do is to trigger the same action when hovering another element that is not #europe li a. I have tried this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var new_map='<span class="map"><span class="s1" /><span class="s2" /><span class="s3" /><span class="s4" /><span class="s5" /><span class="s6" /><span class="s7" /><span class="s8" /><span class="s9" /><span class="s10" /><span class="s11" /><span class="s12" /><span class="s13" /><span class="s14" /><span class="s15" /><span class="s16" /><span class="s17" /><span class="s18" /></span>';
 var new_bg=$("<span>");
 new_bg.addClass("bg");
 $("#carteeurope li a").append(new_map);
 $("#carteeurope li a").append(new_bg);

 $("#menudroite li a").hover(function(){
 $(new_map).appendTo("#carteeurope li a");
 $(new_bg).appendTo("#carteeurope li a");
 });

});
```

It makes something but not the desired effect : it looks like the map can move indeed but not to the good positions (some countries get a white background after several hovers on the second menu).

I would be very grateful if you could help me !

Regards.

PS : some relevant HTML and CSS parts.

The original list

```
<div id="b">
     <ul id="europe" class="bottom five_columns">
      <li id="europe1"><a href="#" title="Albania">Albania</a></li>
      <li id="europe2"><a href="#" title="Andorra">Andorra</a></li>
      <li id="europe3"><a href="#" title="Austria">Austria</a></li>
      ...
```

The menu I would like to add

```
<div id="menudroite">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="France">France</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="Grèce">Grèce</a></li>
...
```

The original CSS

```
#europe,#europe span.bg{background:transparent url('europe-600px.png') no-repeat -9999px 0}
#europe{position:relative;top:0;left:0;display:block;background-position:0 -966px;list-style:none}
 #europe *{padding:0;margin:0;border:0 none;outline:0 none}
  #europe li{cursor:pointer}
  #europe li span{position:absolute;display:block;width:0;height:0;z-index:15}
  #europe li a span.bg{z-index:3}
  #europe li .map{top:0;left:0}
...
 #europe li span{position:absolute;display:block;top:0;left:0;width:0;height:0;z-index:15}
 #europe1 a:hover .bg{top:395px;left:303px;width:20px;height:40px;background-position:-10px -10px} #europe1 .s1{top:401px;left:303px;width:15px;height:32px} #europe1 .s2{top:397px;left:305px;width:8px;height:4px} #europe1 .s3{top:418px;left:318px;width:4px;height:9px}
 #europe2 a:hover .bg{top:385px;left:133px;width:5px;height:6px;background-position:-35px -10px} #europe2 .s1{top:383px;left:131px;width:9px;height:10px}
...
```

Comment: can u show us some `html` (or a working example in http://jsfiddle.com or http://jsbin.com ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved with this function :

```
  $("#menudroite li.menudroitepays a").hover(
   function(){
    var country=$(this).attr("id");
    $("#europe" + country + " a").addClass("active");
   },
   function(){
    var country=$(this).attr("id");
    $("#europe" + country + " a").removeClass("active");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding (**Guess**),  your problem is, when you hover over an `anchor` tag your map is getting empty. I think your problem can be fixed by cloning the `new_map` & `new_bg` before appending to `#carteeurope li a`

your actual code,

```
$("#menudroite li a").hover(function(){
    $(new_map).appendTo("#carteeurope li a");
    $(new_bg).appendTo("#carteeurope li a");
 });
```

I suggest you to do something below,

```
$("#menudroite li a").hover(function(){
    var cache_new_map = new_map;  //cache the new_map 
    var cache_new_bg  = new_bg;   //cache your span
    $(cache_new_map).appendTo("#carteeurope li a");
    $(cache_new_bg).appendTo("#carteeurope li a");
 });
```

The reason for `caching` your `new_map` & `new_bg` is If you are going to **append** the **source** element to some other element, the **source** element gets removed from its original position

**PS**: Actually I don't understand your question, I just guessed the above might be your problem, you could get a good answer from the people around this community if you had provided a online **demo** (link to ur working page). Though you provided some **HTML** & **CSS** it's not enough to answer. Because It is hard to guess what your actual Intention is. `NO OFFENSE`

According to my understanding (if it matches your question ) this solution should work

Comment: You're right, it will be easier with the bigger picture :)

So here it is : http://romain.su.free.fr/beta/

What I would like to do is, when hovering an element of the right menu, having the selected country highlighted. I just tried your solution but I think I forgot something else regarding IDs of the right menu items, I'll work on it again tomorrow. Thanks anyway for your attention !