# Highlight Image Map Area from an LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

I have an image map of a building floor plan. When you hover over a room it highlights as it should. I would like to have a list of names, people who occupy the rooms, off to the side where when you hover over their name, the room they are in is highlighted.

How can I activate the correct image map area from an LI? Preferably with jQuery but JS is okay too.

I think my question is similar to the following question but I am not able to follow it.
[CSS image rollover map and jQuery : how to use a second li list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382417/css-image-rollover-map-and-jquery-how-to-use-a-second-li-list)

Thanks

Comment: Figured it out... apply jQuery's mouseover() even to the <area>.

      $j("#somebody").hover(
   function () {
    $j("#12007").mouseover();
   }, 
   function () {
    $j("#12007").mouseout();
   }
  );

    <map name="LevelOneQ3" id="LevelOne">
       <area shape="rect" coords="8,138,41,168" href="#" id="12007" alt="120.07" target="120.07" />
    </map>

Comment: can you post your current code for your map please?